# 3-manifold theorem reference request or proof

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, 3-manifolds

The following is a theorem of which I have great interest in but cannot find anything about on the internet,

> Every 3-manifold of finite volume comes from identifying sides of some polyhedron

I'm fairly certain that "identifying sides of some polyhedron" may be a simplification of the technical terminology. I believe it is just referring to gluing faces of polyhedron to form closed 3-manifolds. Such examples are given by the Seifert-Weber space, the Poincare homology sphere, the 3-dimensional real projective space, the $\frac{1}{2}$ twist cube space, etc. I'm assuming the proof is based off of [Moise's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moise%27s_theorem) and proceeds as follows,

> Let $M$ be an arbitrary closed 3-manifold. By Moise's theorem we have that $M$ can be tetrahedralized, so we let $T$ be the tetrahedralization of $M$ consisting of tetrahedrons $t_{1},...,t_{n}$. Pick an arbitrary tetrahedra $t_{1}$ of $T$ and proceed to glue $t_{2}$ to $t_{1}$, forming a new polyhedron $P_{2}$, and then glue $t_{3}$ to $P_{2}$ resulting in $P_{3}$, and so on. After all tetrahedra $t_{1},...,t_{n}$ have been glued, we have some resulting polyhedron $P_{n}$. From here, then somehow show that $P_{n}$ can be glued to $M$?

Any references to papers, expository writing, a proof of, or even the formal statement and name of this theorem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should note in your question that this has already been asked elsewhere and similarly on the other side. (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/100029/3-manifold-theorem-reference-request-or-proof)


Comment: Is it not a good idea to post a question on both MO and MSE? I am the same person as the one who asked on MSE.

Comment: Usually no, it is not a good idea; for your particular question, I am pretty sure you'll get more useful answers here than there though. But you *should* note the fact that there is another copy of the question elsewhere (for all sorts of reasons: people might answer here when the answer has already been answered there, thereby wasting effort; &c)

Comment: The answer is yes.  The idea is once you have a triangulation of a connected manifold, you can take your polyhedron to be a regular neighbourhood of a maximal tree in the dual 1-skeleton.  The identifications on the boundary come from inflating the regular neighbourhood to the point where it fills the triangulation. 

Comment: It seems to me that you have already answered your question in the second "blocked text".  The faces of $P_n$ are identified in pairs by looking at the corresponding faces of the triangulation, and by definition this gluing gives back $M$.  What else is there to say?

Comment: It just seems to me that the idea I had is a very hand-wavy proof. Is there some sort of rigorous proof available somewhere with the technical argument?

Comment: Is "finite volume" being used to mean "compact" here?

Comment: Or does finite volume mean that the manifold has some kind of metric (preferably hyperbolic!) and you want a beautiful fundamental domain for the action of $\pi_1$ on the universal cover?  Because these also (almost) exist -- see "Euclidean decompositions of noncompact hyperbolic manifolds" by Epstein and Penner. 

Comment: Samuel, U. Calgary does not appear to have a student directory online. I have received a pdf copy of Philip Franklin 1934 on "A Six Color Problem." I think it is quite reveling about your Klein bottle question. If you would like a copy, email me. Note that I will not necessarily be notified about comments here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the reference that you are looking for is  [this article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.1912)  by Cannon, Floyd, and Parry.

Comment: Scott - This works, but it is more "high powered" than what the original poster is asking for.  Isn't it?

Comment: Sam: Probably so. I heard Jim talk about it a few years ago, and thought it was very interesting.

Comment: @Scott Carter: I'm attempting to read through this and it is a little dense, any additional papers that may make the reading a bit easier or should I pull one of the "descend down through the references until I reach familiar territory"?

Comment: @Samuel Reid, I have not read the article myself. I heard Jim Cannon talk about it. He usually gives very lucid talks, but one finds that there are terribly dense details in the text. My understanding of his work is that it is well worth trying to slog through it.
